# Adding Time Capsule and Airport Express to existing non-Apple network?

Tags: network, airport, time-capsule

OK - lots of info about this but couldn't find anything definitive...

I used to have a VDSL modem (from my internet provider) and Time Capsule for WiFi access. Then the VDSL modem failed (and replacements aren't available) and I needed something urgently, so I bought a TP_Link VDSL wireless router and stuck the TC in a cupboard.

I now need internet access for 3 devices in study in the house that gets an extremely poor (i.e. slow) WiFi signal from the router. I've routed a 15m Ethernet cable from the TP-link router to the room which I plug into the machine (2 x PS4 and Mac Pro) that 'needs' it's faster speed.

But I really need to get my Time Capsule up and running again (for backing up our 4 Mac laptops) and I also have an Airport Express, which got me thinking about making use these to both add Time Machine capability AND improve wifi coverage...

I *think* I have 3 options:

1. Hang the TC off the end of the Ethernet cable in the study, and have
   the devices in there connect to a new 'Study' wifi network provided
   by the TC? Will devices connected to the wifi from the router see
   the TC, connected to the router via Ethernet? Or could the TC create
   WiFi networks with the same SSID and password as that created by the
   TP router?
2. Use the TP router JUST as a modem, put the TC next to the router with a
   6" Ethernet cable and use the TC to provide WiFi coverage for most
   of the house and put the Airport Express on the end of the Ethernet
   cable in the study and configure it to extend (bridge?) the TC's
   WiFi network?
3. Get a separate VDSL modem to replace the TP-Link router and then do
   the same as 2? (which is technically the same I think, but saves the
   clutter of the big router which isn't doing much).

Question: What is the best network configuration given my needs and the equipment I have? IF a new VDSL modem would simplify things, then that's OK. I want to avoid 'unseen problems'such as double-natting, which I might introduce but not be aware of until I get p@wned at CoD die to slow pings etc. :-)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you actually tried to accomplish the goals in options 1 & 2? If you have, but they’ve failed, report your findings.

Comment: @IconDaemon No - I’m guilty of not yet trying these solutions. However I know that with networks, something might *appear* to work, but with unseen issues (had a friend tell me I was ‘double natting’ when attempting something similar  with Apple & non-Apple hardware a few years ago having disabled the Wi-fi part of my old WAP, but all looked good to me) or might not work due to a simple config setting (bridge mode?).

Comment: Posting several questions at once can be hard to answer! You frame the problem very well, but for better answers, do some troubleshooting on your part is essential. Have you considered bypassing the network backup strategy in favor of a local disk backup using external HDs?

Comment: @IconDaemon - OK. Reworded to be one question. I definitely want to use Time Machine as I have the TC sitting there and I don;t want to have to require my wife and kids to find their external HDDs and plug them in at regular intervals.